# Strange behavior of IconTabBar with GenericTile

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Why does the XML tree on the picture looks like shown on the second picture? `MessageStrip` tries to get into the content area of `IconTabBar` even jumping over 4 elements and tiles get out by any means. There are no restrictions in documentation on what can placed in the `IconTabBar` or in the `IconTabFilter`. `GenericTile` is not a layout which is supposed to take the whole place on the screen. How to put tiles into the content of `IconTabBar`?

[image: XML-View Tree]

[image: Result screenshot]

Here's the code of the view:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <IconTabBar id="idTopLevelIconTabBar" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
    <items>
      <IconTabFilter id="start" icon="sap-icon://hint">
        <GenericTile class="sapUiMediumMarginBeginEnd sapUiLargeMarginTop tileLayout"
          header="Sales Fulfillment Application Title"
          subheader="Subtitle"
        >
          <TileContent unit="EUR" footer="Current Quarter">
            <ImageContent src="sap-icon://home-share"/>
          </TileContent>
        </GenericTile>
        <GenericTile class="sapUiMediumMarginBeginEnd sapUiLargeMarginTop tileLayout"
          header="Manage Activity Master Data Type"
          subheader="Subtitle"
        >
          <TileContent />
        </GenericTile>
        <GenericTile class="sapUiMediumMarginBeginEnd sapUiLargeMarginTop tileLayout"
          header="Manage Activity Master Data Type With a Long Title Without an Icon"
          subheader="Subtitle Launch Tile" mode="HeaderMode"
        >
          <TileContent unit="EUR" footer="Current Quarter" />
        </GenericTile>
        <GenericTile class="sapUiMediumMarginBeginEnd sapUiLargeMarginTop tileLayout"
          header="Jessica D. Prince Senior Consultant"
          subheader="Department"
        >
          <TileContent/>
        </GenericTile>
        <MessageStrip
          type="Information"
          showIcon="true"
          text="Another IconTabFilter"
        />
      </IconTabFilter>
      <IconTabFilter id="layouts" icon="sap-icon://bookmark">
        <!-- ... -->
      </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
  </IconTabBar>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Hmm, try to put them in VBox or HBox, to force them to be grouped?

Comment: @Elias now generic tiles are in HBox and message sticks to the bottom of HBox [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/Z4DM8CN.png)

Comment: @NancyT What's the UI5 version? And what does the `tileLayout` CSS class do? Looks fine in here: https://jsbin.com/yikeyuc/edit?js,output. The only difference is probably the UI5 version and the missing `tileLayout` in my demo.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann tileLayout class has just one property: `float: left`. The real difference was MessageStrip's class `sapUiLargeMarginTop` in your example, it made that distance between GenericTiles and MessageStrip. It helped, thanks a lot!

Comment: @NancyT Oh, yea that `sapUiLargeMarginTop` was just added to give some room. Anyhow, I wasn't able to reproduce [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVUdz.png) with the given code. Would've been nice if the actual code were provided to reproduce the "strange behavior". But now it seems to be resolved. Please add an answer below and accept it as a solution to let others know.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to **remove my custom CSS** (e.g. `tileLayout`) and to add any margin class (e.g. `"sapUiLargeMarginTop"`) to the Message Strip so that Generic Tile fits inside an IconTabFilter.

[The result](https://jsbin.com/yikeyuc/edit?js,output)

Comment: Please accept your own answer to let others know that the issue is resolved by now.